# how to convert one dataframe to another dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

ratings.head()

```
    critic  title   rating
0   Jack Matthews   Lady in the Water   3.0
1   Jack Matthews   Snakes on a Plane   4.0
2   Jack Matthews   You Me and Dupree   3.5
3   Jack Matthews   Superman Returns    5.0
4   Jack Matthews   The Night Listener  3.0
```

I want to make it looks like

```
critic  Just My Luck    Lady in the Water   Snakes on a Plane   Superman Returns    The Night Listener  You Me and Dupree

Claudia Puig    3.0 NaN 3.5 4.0 4.5 2.5
Gene Seymour    1.5 3.0 3.5 5.0 3.0 3.5
Jack Matthews   NaN 3.0 4.0 5.0 3.0 3.5
Lisa Rose   3.0 2.5 3.5 3.5 3.0 2.5
Mick LaSalle    2.0 3.0 4.0 3.0 3.0 2.0
Toby    NaN NaN 4.5 4.0 NaN 1.0
```

I tried to use the

```
movie_rating= ratings.pivot(index='critic', columns='title',values='rating')
```

but it create the extra column name.  like

```
title   Just My Luck    Lady in the Water   Snakes on a Plane   Superman Returns    The Night Listener  You Me and Dupree
critic                      
Claudia Puig    3.0 NaN 3.5 4.0 4.5 2.5
Gene Seymour    1.5 3.0 3.5 5.0 3.0 3.5
Jack Matthews   NaN 3.0 4.0 5.0 3.0 3.5
Lisa Rose   3.0 2.5 3.5 3.5 3.0 2.5
Mick LaSalle    2.0 3.0 4.0 3.0 3.0 2.0
Toby    NaN NaN 4.5 4.0 NaN 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not extra columns you are seeing.  Those are the names of the index for the rows and columns.  The row index is named `'critic'` and the columns index is named `'title'`.  To make the pivoted data frame appear without them, you can simply set the `name` parameter to `None` for the `index` and `columns`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'critic':list('AABBCC'), 
                   'title':['hello','world']*3, 
                   'rating':[4,3,6,2,3,2]}

p = df.pivot(index='critic', columns='title',values='rating')
p
# returns:
title   hello  world
critic
A           4      3
B           6      2
C           3      2
```

You can see that `title` and `critic` are the name properties of the `columns` and `index` respectively

```
p.columns, p.index
# returns:
(Index(['hello', 'world'], dtype='object', name='title'),
 Index(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object', name='critic'))
```

To remove the names from appearing, you can simply overwrite the `name` property for the `index` and `columns` objects.

```
p.index.name = None
p.columns.name = None
p
# returns:
   hello  world
A      4      3
B      6      2
C      3      2
```